# How to calculate rowMeans of columns with similar colnames in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with similar colnames.
I want to calculate rowMeans of columns A and B.
How can I do rowMeans between all A and B columns?

```
df <- data.frame(A1=c(1,2),A2=c(3,4),A3=c(5,6),A4=c(7,7),A5=c(8,8),A6=c(9,9)) 
colnames(df)<- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
```

Comment: In general, having identical column names in R makes things difficult when processing things. For instance, after your column renaming above, what should happen when you do `df$A`? It is ambiguous. Further, what do you mean by *"calculate rowMeans between"*? It's the between part that doesn't make sense to me ... calculating is not a "between" thing.

Comment: Yes. You are right. "between" is not appropriate word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can iterate over unique names, subset them from original dataframe and take `rowMeans`.

```
sapply(c("A", "B"), function(x) rowMeans(df[,colnames(df) == x]))

#     A    B
#[1,] 2 6.67
#[2,] 3 7.00
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be `split` by the similar column names into a `list` and then get the `rowMeans`

```
i1 <- grep("^(A|B)", names(df))
sapply(split.default(df[i1], names(df)[i1]), rowMeans)
#     A        B
#[1,] 2 6.666667
#[2,] 3 7.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

An other option using the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df[, "rn"] <- 1:nrow(df)

df %>% 
  gather(letter, value, -rn) %>% 
  mutate(letter = str_extract(letter, "[:alpha:]")) %>% 
  group_by(letter, rn) %>% 
  summarize(sum = mean(value)) %>% 
  filter(letter %in% c("A", "B"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   letter [2]
#>   letter    rn   sum
#>   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A          1  2   
#> 2 A          2  3   
#> 3 B          1  6.67
#> 4 B          2  7
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to submit the dataframe by the columns you want, and then apply the `rowMeans()` function.

```
df <- data.frame(A1=c(1,2),A2=c(3,4),A3=c(5,6),A4=c(7,7),A5=c(8,8),A6=c(9,9)) 
colnames(df)<- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
rowSums(df[,which(colnames(df) %in% c("A","B"))])
#[1] 24 27
```

However, as r2evans pointed out in the comment, you should avoid columns with the same names. You would just want to get the position of the columns that determine the start and end of the number of columns between and subset.

```
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("A",1:2), paste0("B", 1:3), "C1")
strt <- which(colnames(df) == "A1")
end <- which(colnames(df) == "B3")
columrange <- strt:end
rowSums(df[,columrange])
#[1] 24 27
```

There are many ways to subset by column names. If you didn't rename your columns in your example, you could use `grepl()` to find them:

```
df[,grepl("A",colnames(df)) | grepl("B",colnames(df))]
#  A1 A2 B1 B2 B3
#1  1  3  5  7  8
#2  2  4  6  7  8
```